# What is the difference between signed and normal short

Tags: c++, signed, short

What is the difference between signed and normal short in c++? Is the range is different?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `normal` is not a C++ keyword.

Comment: by "normal short" he is meaning "short", without any "(un)signed" specifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`short` is `signed` by default, so there is no difference.

Comment: Out of curiosity: then why the `signed short` is allowed? To simplify the grammar?

Comment: @pmor In most languages I know, redundant modifiers are allowed. It can be `public` (when public visibility is the default), `private` (when private visibility is the default), or in this case, `signed` (when signed is the default). It makes the language more consistent, which is, in general, a desired property.

Comment: A practical application I can think of is meta-programming, be it a macro or some kind of a script. It's easier to generate declarations with pseudo-code logic like `Declaration A -> type: short, signed: true; Declaration B -> type: char, signed: false` (which should produce `signed short <identifier>`; `unsigned char <identifier>`) than to keep track of the signed/unsigned defaults for specific types (for `short` the default is signed, for `char` it's implementation-defined, in this particular case).

Answer (score 3):

The names `signed short int`, `signed short`, `short int` and `short` are synonymes and mean same type in C++.

Comment: Note that the `signed char` and `char` integer types are _not_ the same. A `char` is either the same as `unsigned char` or as `signed char`, you don't know which one (OK, OK, I lied; it depends on your architecture).

Comment: @vonbrand Yes and with `wchar_t` or `float` one may not even qualify it with `signed` but that might go too far from OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Integers are signed by default in C++, which IMO brings the existence of the `signed` keyword into question. Technically, it is redundant, maybe it does contribute with some clarity, but hardly anyone uses it in production. Everyone is pretty much aware integers are signed by default. I honestly can't remember the last time I've seen `signed` in production code.

As for floats and doubles - they cannot be unsigned at all, they are always signed.

In this regard C++ syntax is a little redundant, at least IMO. There is a number of different ways to say the same thing, e.g. `signed short int`, `signed short`, `short int` and `short` , and what you say still might be platform or even compiler dependent.

Frameworks like Qt for example declare their own conventions which are shorter and informative, like for example:

quint8, quint16, quint32, quint64 are all unsigned integers, with the number signifying the size in bits, in the same logic:

qint8, qint16, qint32, qint64 are signed integers with the respective bit width.

`uint` is, at least for me, much more preferable to either `unsigned` or `unsigned int`, in the same logic you also have `ushort` which is preferable to `unsigned short int`. There is also `uchar` to complete the short-hard family.

Comment: `signed` is sometimes used for bit-packed members of structs and for `char` so the keyword will stay useful forever in language.